# ext.tree.treepanel doesn't show the directory, only the root, repeated

Tags: extjs

```
that.getStore().setProxy({
type:'ajax',
url:'dir.json',
reader:{
    type:'json',
    root:'tree'
}})
```

first time to use stackoverflow,^^||,the result is like this, because it's my work code, it's not convenient to show more. i just want to know is there anybody have problems like this, and can you help me, thanks in advance

[the directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyuhF.png)

[the dir.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAg7s.png)

Comment: If you're pointing at a static file, then it's always going to load the same data. It expects you to return the correct data for that node.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand, my dir.json has all the directories i need, but it only displays the root, like svn, when i clicked the svn, it then also display the svn, but on the next level,

Comment: The roots don't match. You've used `tree` for the top level and `children` for the lower levels. They need to be the same thing.

Comment: oh, yes, you're right, it works now, thank you very very much!!!